# downloading a file in box using php

Tags: php, api, curl, box-api

I'm trying to download a file from Box using API, but I'm not getting any responce.

Here's my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.box.com/2.0/files/3934151224/content");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: BoxAuth api_key={myAPIkey}&auth_token={myToken}"));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r ($result);
```

When i try to run it i get a blank page, nothing in responce nor 'save as' window.

what is that i am missing. Please help. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How big is the file? You're probably running out of memory, for one of two reasons (or both):

1. You are storing the entire response in memory by assigning it to a variable. Consider writing the cURL output to a file, using the CURLOPT_FILE option, and a valid file resource.
2. You *may* have output buffering enabled, which would also hold all of the output in memory AGAIN, when you print_r the result. You can easily check this by doing a print ob_get_level(); right before your cURL call.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.The file size is 19kb.Can u please show me the modification in my code or any link that will give me idea about this issue..

Comment: What happens if you `var_dump( curl_error( $ch ) )` AFTER the curl_exec but BEFORE the curl_close?

Comment: I am getting `string '' (length=0)`  Any other info you need?

Answer (score 0):

I came to this solution:

```
//set the headers
$headers = array('Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=API_KEY&auth_token=AUTH_TOKEN');

//set the options
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.box.com/2.0/files/".$fileid."/content");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); //returns to a variable instead of straight to page
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); //returns headers as part of output
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); //I needed this for it to work
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2); //I needed this for it to work

$headers = curl_exec($curl); //because the returned page is blank, this will include headers only

//parses the headers string into an array
$items = array();
$item = strtok($headers, " ");

while ($item !== false) {
  $items[] = $item;
  $item = strtok(" ");
}

//redirects to the 14th item in the array (link value) - 17 characters because of
//dodgy header parsing above.
header('Location: '.substr($items[14], 0, -17));

echo curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

This is because the Box API actually returns a blank page with a 302 redirect header, not the file contents. This way you can grab the header and fiddle with it, and not have to download the file on the server before sending to the client.

I know its a bit hacky in the way I handle the header string but that's not the important bit, I'll clean it up later.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following code to download box files

```
   $url = "https://api.box.com/2.0/files/$fileId/content?access_token=$accessToken"

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $contents = curl_exec($ch);

    set_time_limit(0);
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: '.$filesize);

    print $contents;
```